# Show that $n^{12} + 64$ has at least 4 non-trivial factors.

Tags: number-theory

> Show that for every integer $n>1$, $n^{12} + 64$ has at least four factors different from $1$ and the number.(It has at least four non-trivial factors.)

My attempt:

We can expand $n^{12} + 64$  in the following way :

$=>n^{12} + 64 = (n^4)^3 + (2^2)^3$

$=>n^{12} + 64 = (n^4 + 2^2)((n^4)^2 + (2^2)^2 - (2^2)(n^4))$

$=>n^{12} + 64 = ((n^2 + 2)^2 - 2(2)(n^2))((n^4)^2 + (2^2)^2 - (2^2)(n^4)) $

$=>n^{12} + 64 = (n^2  + 2 + 2n)(n^2 + 2 - 2n)(n^8 + 2^4 - 4n^4)$

i.e there are 3 different factors.

How can I prove that there is one more factor ?.

Update: I think we are already done, because we got the following factors:

1.$(n^2  + 2 + 2n)$

2.$(n^2 + 2 - 2n)$

3.$(n^8 + 2^4 - 4n^4)$

4.$(n^2  + 2 + 2n)(n^2 + 2 - 2n)$

5.$(n^2  + 2 + 2n)(n^8 + 2^4 - 4n^4)$

6.$(n^2 + 2 - 2n)(n^8 + 2^4 - 4n^4)$

Clearly, we have got 6 non-trivial factors.(None of them can be one.)

Comment: $x^{12}+64=(x^2 - 2 x + 2) (x^2 + 2 x + 2) (x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 - 4 x + 4) (x^4 + 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 4 x + 4)$.

Comment: Note:  it is not true that your number is always divisible by $8$ (this is true if and only if  $n$ is even).

Comment: The third factor should be $n^8-4n^4+16$ which is the product of two polynomials of fourth degree in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: @lulu, its a typo, the number is actually$n^8 - 4n^2 + 16$

Comment: @lulu: And if $n$ is even, then $n^{12}+64$ has at least 7 factors: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64. and $32n+1$.

Comment: I would start with Sophie Germain $u^4 + 4 v^4$   factors.

Comment: I wonder how to answer the "non trivial factor" part of the question. How to show that for instance $x^4-2x^3+2x^2-4x+4\neq 1$ and $x$ ?

Comment: @zwim $x^4-2x^3+2x^2-4x+4$ is always positive, and is upward-facing. And while it goes below $1$ on the reals, you can check the small integers to show that on the integers the only trivial solution has $x=1$, which is excluded from the problem.

Comment: It seems rather a tall order to expect someone to factorise $n^8-4n^2+16$ into two factors, each with 5 terms. Is there an easier way to show that it is reducible?

Answer (score 1):

Well we can write-

$n^{12}+64=(n^4)^3+4^3$

$=(n^4+4)(n^8-4n^4+16)$

$=[(n^2)^2+2(n^2)(2)+2^2-(2n)^2](n^8-4^2+4n^6-4n^6+12n^4-16n^4+16n^2-16n^2)$

$=[(n^2+2)^2-(2n)^2][(n^8+4^2+4n^4+4n^6+8n^4+16n^2)-(4n^6+16n^2+16n^4)]$

$=(n^2+2n+2)(n^2-2n+2)[(n^4+2n^2+4)^2-(2n^3+4n)^2]$

$=(n^2+2n+2)(n^2-2n+2)(n^4+2n^3+2n^2+4n+4)(n^4-2n^3+2n^2-4n+4)$